# How to affect a variable outside of a function without using globals

Tags: php, function, variables, global

Need some code examples on how to affect a variable outside of a function without using globals. Also I want to know where should I use global and where not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kevin Yank prefers non-global method for affecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* way to affect a variable in another scope without using globals is to use [**references**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). You can define a function that takes it's arguments by reference by prefixing the argument with `&`. For example:

```
function increment(&$var) {
  $var++;
}

$int = 1;
increment($int);
echo $int; // 2
```

In answer to the question "when should I use globals" - never. They make the program flow confusing and invite errors and unexpected behaviour, and they also make code less portable, as it relies on variable names in another scope.

Comment: Then PHP should abandon that function in newer versions

Comment: PHP rarely drops features. New releases usually aim to be as backwards-compatible as possible, and old scripts may rely on globals. Another point there is that there are some very, *very* rare circumstances in which they can be useful. Much like `goto` - people will tell you never to use them, because it is simpler than saying "only use them if you understand exactly what you are doing and all the implications of it". It is much easier and safer to tell novice programmers to never user these features, then when they become more experienced you can tell them otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use global variables its evil.

for second part of question you can do like this:

```
function test(&$param) {
    $param = 'new';
}

$test = 'old';
test($test);
echo $test; // returns 'new'
```

Comment: what does that '&' mean ? I'm new to php

Comment: Why they are evil. What's evil doing inside PHP ?

Comment: & means pass the variable by reference rather than value. Global variables aren't "evil", but they're generally bad programming practice as they tend to make things confusing and lead to unexpected errors.

Comment: about evil there is a lot questions and answers on this site. for what  `&` is read here http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = 'value';

echo $var; //outputs "value"

a($var);
echo $var //outputs "new value; func a";

b('some other sutff', 'etc');
echo $var; //outputs "new value; func b";

function a(&$var2affect){

 $var2affect = 'new value; func a';

 return;

}

function b($some_var, $some_second_var){

  global $var;

  $var = 'new vaule; func b';

}
```

or just tell us what specifically you want to do

> sorry for my english